# How to let `named` (bind9) forward certain domains to a different nameserver?

Tags: dns, bind

In `dnsmasq`, it's possible to forward domains to different nameservers. How can I do that in `named`?

```
server=/foo.com/10.0.10.1
server=/vpn.foo.com/8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work for BIND9:

```
zone "foo.com" IN {
    type forward;
    forwarders {
        10.0.10.1;
    };
};

zone "vpn.foo.com" IN {
    type forward;
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
    };
};
```

Comment: You might also need to replace `dnssec-validation auto;` with `dnssec-validation no;` in named.conf.options.

Comment: Does this also supports wildcards?

Comment: The [BIND 9.9 Configuration Reference](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html) doesn't explicitly say, but since the zone name needs to be a valid zone that could be used with the `$ORIGIN` directive in a zone file, I don't believe you can use wildcards for the zone name.

Comment: Also a `forward only` option might be meaningful here.